# XAMPP + PHP to Node.js

Tags: php, node.js

I'm planning on converting a small PHP codebase (less than 1000 lines) to Node.js. It's a web app that contains about 50k lines of JS, so I figured I'd move it to Node.js. (Plus, PHP sucks donkey balls.) There's a few static files (CSS, HTML, etc.) that I'll be serving with the `node-static` package. My issue is with my PHP files that are not static.

For example, I have a search page that runs on a GET variable. I tack on `?keyword=blah` onto the end of the URL and the PHP script searches the DB and outputs HTML for the browser. How do I replicate this behavior in Node.js? (In other words, how can I create a server to listen at `localhost/search.html` and accept GET variables in the URL?)

I know I can change the way searches are done to accomplish this, but I'd really like to figure out how to replicate this behavior since I have several scripts that act the same way.

EDIT: As for the database, I'm actually using OrientDB. But I don't connect directly to it, I use a set of Java services that I post JSON requests to. So really, all I need to be able to do is post a JSON request (synchronously) and output HTML.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Are you able to move to Mongo?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify that in the original question.

Comment: Take a look at [Express](http://expressjs.com/), that's a pretty easy framework which can handle both static and dynamic requests.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I searched for over an hour and Express didn't come up. Thank you, it's exactly what I need. Feel free to answer the question with that and I'll accept.

Comment: @GJK I gave you code sample :)

Comment: OP suck donkey balls. jokes aside, PHP is superior to node.js in one very important aspect: it does not require callbacks when you issue a blocking operation such as database access. here is a shameless plug too my own PHP project: http://sqlrabbit.org it works great.

Comment: You can't compare PHP and Node.js, you compare PHP and Javascript. And as most people will agree (even those who use it), PHP is a horribly designed language. While Javascript isn't perfect, it's not nearly as bad as PHP. Also, callbacks are the number one reason TO use Node.js. If you have a single DB request that takes forever, it'll freeze your entire PHP server, since PHP isn't threaded. If you want quick response times, you'll use Node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

Create a new [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) app

```
"express myapp"
```

Install all the dependencies

```
"cd myapp && npm install".
```

In app.js, make sure you require the "url" package before "**var app**"

```
var url = require('url');
```

Add a new route to "app.js" so that it looks for any GET requests to "search.html"

```
app.get('/search.html', function(req, res) {

    // Process the request for the GET variables
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query; // These are all your GET variables
    var search_keyword = query.keyword;

    if(search_keyword) {
        // The keyword indeed exists
        console.log(search_keyword);

    }
    res.end();
});
```

If you run the app and go to "search.html?keyword=haha", your console will output "haha". You can do anything after that with the keyword.

Comment: If any of you people in the future are using Typescript, `node.d.ts` from MS describes the `query` member as a string when it's really an object. Just FYI.